# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, doctrine

When i run this Script in  below i have this error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in

and i run before other the same Script but for other Tables  :

```
$row = array();
        $infos = array();

        $db=mysqli_connect($this->hostname_mysql, $this->username_mysql, $this->password_mysql,$this->database_mysql)  or die(mysql_error());
        mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8');
        mysqli_select_db($db,$this->database_mysql);

        $sqlprocessdechets="select * from t_lig_dect_fs order by decht_id ASC";
        $resultdechets=mysqli_query($db,$sqlprocessdechets) or die( mysql_error() . "<br>$sqlprocessdechets" );
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultdechets) )
        {

                $infos[]=$row;


        } // while

        return $infos;
```

how can i resolved that thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you use mysqli with doctrine, and a framework like zend framework 2 ? Maybe your problems comes from here first.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

Add this above on your php script, the memory which holds array values depends upon the server's set MAX capacity.

so you need to set it unlimited.

Comment: After adding this line of code... I am facing 503 Error on the site